# Fantasy book about an (orphan?) girl named Opal, involves gems or stones

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much about the book but I read the book when I was younger and I remember really enjoying it so I would like to find the book to have the chance to read it again. I'll try to add as much information about it as possible.

Things I'm sure of:

- The story involved a girl named Opal​
- The story revolved around some sort of gems or stones, I'm not entirely sure the role these gems or stones had but they were very important
- I read the book when I was about 10, so the book came out no later than 2008
- The cover of the book was black or another dark color
- It's a fantasy/adventure book
- hardcover

Other things I think are associated with the book but I could be wrong:

- I believe the character Opal was young, no older than her early teens
- Had no parents? I believe she lived with an old man - possibly her grandfather
- I believe the cover of the book might have had a circle of some sort on the cover? I am really not sure of this
- I believe it is part of a series

I know the book is 100% not any of the following:

- *The Prophecy of the Stones*
- *Deltora quest*

Comment: I read the title and the description, and I was absolutely sure it was the *Prophecy of the stones*. Are you sure you didn't mix it up with another book?

Comment: Apart from the name of the heroine, it sounds a lot like the comic book *Amethyst, Princess of Gemworld*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amethyst,_Princess_of_Gemworld. The villain is called Dark Opal.

Comment: is it possible you could have mixed it up with this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_of_Kazan

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is one of the stories from the [book](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618004631/http://www.scholastic.com/teachers/book/tales-deltora#cart/cleanup) [*Tales of Deltora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Deltora). It’s not part of *Deltora Quest*, more a background of how they came to be, and I know this book has a young girl named Opal and has a lot about gems in her story.

> Opal the Dreamer was born as the daughter of Liza and Dodd, two farmers who owned an apple orchard and later discovered opals on their land. Opal was born after this discovery and named for the stones, which surrounded her constantly throughout her early life. As time went by, Opal began having dreams of other places and events, some of them apparently foreboding the future. After she dreamed of a man's death and it occurred, her parents swore her to secrecy and Opal came to believe that her dreams had caused the tragedy.
>
> Her dreams would continue, however, and Opal would be secluded from others as she grew into adulthood and eventually realised the truth behind her dreams. After having a dream of the man who would save the Land of Dragons by creating a magic belt, she tried to warn her parents but would not be heard, and so travelled to the nearby city of Hira to speak her warnings to others. Sadly, she was not heeded, and after a year of attempting to convince the people of the truth, she dreamed of "the man of fire and iron" again and left her home region to seek him out. Eventually she came to Del, where she found a blacksmith-though not the one of her visions-and eventually became his wife, but was sadly forgotten by her own people and those of Del.
>
> <sub>[Deltora Quest Wiki, Tales of Deltora (real)](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_Deltora_(real))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It’s called [*Through Wolf's Eyes*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/66317.Through_Wolf_s_Eyes) by Jane Lindskold. It took forever to figure it out and only did accidentally because I’m currently re reading it.

> Firekeeper only vaguely remembers a time when she didn't live with her
> "family," a pack of "royal wolves"-bigger, stronger, and smarter than
> normal wolves. Now her pack leaders are sending her back to live among
> the humans, as they promised her mother years ago.
>
> Some of the humans think she may be the lost heir to their throne.
> This could be good-and it could be very, very dangerous. In the months
> to come, learning to behave like a human will turn out to be more
> complicated than she'd ever imagined.
>
> But though human ways might be stranger than anything found in the
> forest, the infighting in the human's pack is nothing Firekeeper
> hasn't seen before. That, she understands just fine. She's not your
> standard-issue princess-and this is not your standard-issue fairy tale

The other gems are other characters (siblings) all named after gems or stones

> *"He was permitted no further time to worry. The towering
> wooden doors at the far end of the hall were beginning to
> open and the steward’s trumpet voice announced: “Grand Duke Gadman, Lord Rolfston Redbriar and Lady Melina Shield, with Sapphire, Jet, Opal, Ruby, and Citrine Shield.”"*

Comment: The other gems are other characters (siblings) all named after gems or stones.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to explain the ways in which this matches the story described in the question. Adding a synopsis and a link to whichever site you copied and pasted that synopsis from would be helpful too. See [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/122024) for more tips on how to write a good story ID answer. You might also want to take the [tour] to learn more about the site in general.

Answer (score -1):

Are you thinking storm glass by Snyder?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please check out [How to write a good story-ID answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/31394) - ideally, you could [edit] your post to include more info about this story and how it fits what was described in the question you're answering.