# Fantasy YA/Pre teen book Identification with female main character and involving gemstones

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to remember the name of a book I read a long time ago and I only have bits and pieces to go off of. So far google has not helped me. Here is what I do remember:

- Main character is named after a gemstone (I believe it was ruby, opal or maybe emerald).  Either that or she has a gemstone in her possession.
- Starts out in a village.
- She goes on some quest through the forest (I vaguely remember her not supposed to stray from the path) and encounters will-o-wisps.
- There was one scene where she is in a fae castle.
- Fights villain at the end. I’m pretty sure it is a female villain.

I know this is not a lot to go on but it is really bugging me! I remember thinking so highly of this book and now that I’m older I would like to reread it to see if it lives up to my own hype. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Was her name Opal, like this other question ([Fantasy book about an (orphan?) girl named Opal, involves gems or stones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/213330/82909))? Are any of the suggestions there correct?

Comment: It isn’t Deltora Quest and it isn’t any of the books mentioned in the other post either, like Prophecy of the Stones. I am beginning to wonder if I just imagined it.

Answer (score 1):

The gemstone element put me in mind of a series I read as a kid called Deltora Quest. It doesn't match very closely to some of your other descriptions, but here is what Wikipedia had to say about the eponymous quest:

> Their quest is to find the seven gems of the fabled Belt of Deltora: the topaz, the ruby, the opal, the lapis lazuli, the emerald, the amethyst, and the diamond. The gems each have a special power and are hidden in dangerous locations around Deltora.

> [image: Deltora Quest Covers]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like prophecy of the stones by Flavia Bujor. Main characters are Jade, Opal, and Amber, who go on a quest together after meeting.

I randomly thought of this book tonight. I read it as a kid and could only remember a few details. Found it through a lot of Google searching.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you show that any of the other details mentioned in the question are matches?  Does she find will-o-wisps when travelling through a forest?  Is there a fae castle?